# Rename files to add leading zeros to numbers

Tags: rename

I've tried a bunch of examples of the rename command but I can't figure out the syntax to do what I want.

I have a bunch of files labeled something like

```
File_Ex_1.jpg
File_Ex_2.jpg
File_Ex_3.jpg
File_Ex_4.jpg
...
File_Ex_10.jpg
File_Ex_11.jpg
etc.
```

I want to change only some of them by inserting a `0` so that the file names have the same number of characters.

So I want `File_Ex_1.jpg` to go to `File_Ex_01.jpg`, `File_Ex_2.jpg` to `File_Ex_02.jpg`

How do you do this with the rename command?

This [`rename` command](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) was installed via [home-brew](http://brewformulas.org/rename) on a Mac.
Output of `rename -v`:

```
rename -v
Usage:
    rename [switches|transforms] [files]

    Switches:

    -0/--null (when reading from STDIN)
    -f/--force or -i/--interactive (proceed or prompt when overwriting)
Wide character in print at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/Pod/Text.pm line 286.

    -g/--glob (expand "*" etc. in filenames, useful in Windows™ CMD.EXE)
    -k/--backwards/--reverse-order
    -l/--symlink or -L/--hardlink
    -M/--use=*Module*
    -n/--just-print/--dry-run
    -N/--counter-format
    -p/--mkpath/--make-dirs
    --stdin/--no-stdin
    -t/--sort-time
    -T/--transcode=*encoding*
    -v/--verbose

    Transforms, applied sequentially:

    -a/--append=*str*
    -A/--prepend=*str*
    -c/--lower-case
    -C/--upper-case
    -d/--delete=*str*
    -D/--delete-all=*str*
    -e/--expr=*code*
    -P/--pipe=*cmd*
    -s/--subst *from* *to*
    -S/--subst-all *from* *to*
    -x/--remove-extension
    -X/--keep-extension
    -z/--sanitize
    --camelcase --urlesc --nows --rews --noctrl --nometa --trim (see manual)
```

Answer (score 25):

Try with this:

```
rename -e 's/\d+/sprintf("%02d",$&)/e' -- *.jpg
```

Example:

```
$ ls
Device_Ex_10.jpg  Device_Ex_1.jpg  Device_Ex_4.jpg  Device_Ex_7.jpg
Device_Ex_11.jpg  Device_Ex_2.jpg  Device_Ex_5.jpg  Device_Ex_8.jpg
Device_Ex_12.jpg  Device_Ex_3.jpg  Device_Ex_6.jpg  Device_Ex_9.jpg
$ rename -e 's/\d+/sprintf("%02d",$&)/e' -- *.jpg
$ ls
Device_Ex_01.jpg  Device_Ex_04.jpg  Device_Ex_07.jpg  Device_Ex_10.jpg
Device_Ex_02.jpg  Device_Ex_05.jpg  Device_Ex_08.jpg  Device_Ex_11.jpg
Device_Ex_03.jpg  Device_Ex_06.jpg  Device_Ex_09.jpg  Device_Ex_12.jpg
```

I took the reference from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417979/batch-rename-sequential-files-by-padding-with-zeroes

Here adapted to your particular `rename` implementation.

Comment: This looks like a proper call for the Perl-based version of rename, which the asker doesn't appear to have.

Comment: Is there a good reference to explain what these commands mean?  Like what the + sign does.

This is close, except I guess the real format for my filenames is

Device1_Ex_1.jpg

Where this syntax would turn that into Device01_Ex_1.jpg and not Device1_Ex_01.jpg

Comment: @dhag The asker definitely has a Perl-based version, both because they aren't running Linux so they don't have the util-linux `rename`, and because the output of `rename -v` explicitly mentions Perl.

Comment: Yes, OK, my wording was terrible. I should have said "the version that accepts a Perl expression as one of its parameters". This still looks like a wrong answer, doesn't it?

Comment: Interestingly, while this appears to contradict the help text which, if I understand correctly, requires `-e` before the Perl code, this call actually works with the rename utility that comes with macOS. I retract my initial comment.

Comment: This is the method I've been using to fix episode numbers on my plex server.  It's made me love rename. Although I would've done it as "rename -e 's/(\d+)/sprintf("%02d",$1)/e' *.jpg". More or less the same though.

Comment: OK, this works.  Thanks!  Wish I knew what the commands mean though -- reading the perl regular expressions syntax page doesn't make it very clear on how to write the expressions.

Comment: This doesn't work if order needs to be maintained, since *.jpg will order 'Device_Ex_9.jpg' after 'Device_Ex_99.jpg'. See my answer below for a fix.

Comment: sprintf isn't a thing on zsh on Mac

Answer (score 6):

With the version of rename that you seem to be using, the following
expression should do the transformation you request (example with a
directory containing files named `File_Ex_{1..11}.jpg`):

```
$ rename -n -e 's/_(\d\.)/_0$1/g' -- *.jpg
'File_Ex_1.jpg' would be renamed to 'File_Ex_01.jpg'
'File_Ex_2.jpg' would be renamed to 'File_Ex_02.jpg'
'File_Ex_3.jpg' would be renamed to 'File_Ex_03.jpg'
'File_Ex_4.jpg' would be renamed to 'File_Ex_04.jpg'
'File_Ex_5.jpg' would be renamed to 'File_Ex_05.jpg'
'File_Ex_6.jpg' would be renamed to 'File_Ex_06.jpg'
'File_Ex_7.jpg' would be renamed to 'File_Ex_07.jpg'
'File_Ex_8.jpg' would be renamed to 'File_Ex_08.jpg'
'File_Ex_9.jpg' would be renamed to 'File_Ex_09.jpg'
```

(Remove flag `-n` to actually do the renaming.)

The argument to `-e` is a Perl search-and-replace expression; where
`_(\d\.)` matches am underscore followed by a single digit and then a
dot, and replaces the underscore with `_0`, thus inserting a leading
zero. `$1` is a back-reference to the group within parentheses, the
digit and dot, and leaves it unchanged in the new file name.

Answer (score 2):

While it can be done with `prename` command, I would like to provide a python alternative to that:

```
$ ls
File_Ex_1.jpg  File_Ex_2.jpg  File_Ex_3.jpg  File_Ex_4.jpg

$ ./pad_zeros.py *                                                                                                       

$ ls
File_Ex_01.jpg  File_Ex_02.jpg  File_Ex_03.jpg  File_Ex_04.jpg  pad_zeros.py*
```

The `pad_zeros.py` script is simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys,os,re

for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    if __file__ in file: continue
    words = re.split('_|\.',file)
    words[-2] = words[-2].zfill(2)
    new_name = "_".join(words[:-1]) + "." + words[-1]
    os.rename(file,new_name)
```

It takes arguments on command-line, iterates over them, and pads zeros using `.zfill()` command(in this particular case to two characters). Since we're operating on all files in the same folder, glob-star can be used.

Comment: This is the best answer adjustable to however many files need to be renamed.

Comment: Although I am getting an `Anomalous backslash in string: '\g'. String constant might be missing an r prefix. (anomalous-backslash-in-string)` error

Comment: could not run it so I `chmod 755`'d it. and now getting a boat load of errors:`import-im6.q16: not authorized `sys' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
import-im6.q16: not authorized `os' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
import-im6.q16: not authorized `re' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
./renameLeadZero.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `if'
./renameLeadZero.py: line 6: `    if __file__ in file: continue'
` I am using a conda env so probably have to designate the interpreter on the shebang differently?

Comment: @mLstudent33 That's peculiar. The error in your second comment probably stems from a backslash in one of the filenames. Python regex thinks it's a special backslash escape. We probably can get around that by adding `repr()` around `file` in `re.split()` line, or string formatting (  https://stackoverflow.com/q/18707338/3701431 ) but we'll need to take into account whether it's Python3 or Python2.7 we have on the system - their string formatting is different just a bit. For the error in the third comment, I cannot confirm nor deny - never worked with Conda.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have done with `ls + awk + sh` for the sake of challenge:

```
ls -1 | awk -F_ '{printf "%s%02d.jpg\n", "mv "$0" "$1"_"$2"_", $3}' | sh

-F_ ............... field separator
%s ................ string to "mv "$0" "$1"_"$2"_"
%02d .............. our numeric field with leading zeros
```

To just see the command with no modifications remove the `| sh`

Comment: In general, providing commands in plain text to `sh`, after processing unknown filenames, is vulnerable to code injection. Think of a file named `1 2;rm -rf ~;_Ex_1.jpg`.

Comment: For sure [thanasisp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/216907/thanasisp), but as I have said we can see the command before runing it simply by removing the `| sh`.

Answer (score 0):

One answer above gives:

`rename -e 's/\d+/sprintf("%02d",$&)/e' -- *.jpg`

However, that gives incorrect results for me, since *.jpg sorts the files in strict numerical order. Running `rename` with the `-n` flag for a dry run gives me:

```
rename(9999.jpg, frames_0000039996.jpg) 
rename(999.jpg, frames_0000039997.jpg) 
rename(99.jpg, frames_0000039998.jpg) 
rename(9.jpg, frames_0000039999.jpg)
```

Correct results can be had with:

`rename 's/.+/our $i; sprintf("frames_%010d.jpg", 0+$i++)/e' $(ls -1 | sort -V)`

which gives

```
rename(9999.jpg, frames_0000039996.jpg)
rename(999.jpg, frames_0000039997.jpg)
rename(99.jpg, frames_0000039998.jpg)
rename(9.jpg, frames_0000039999.jpg)
```

with the `-n` flag.